# What is the purpose of ordering answers SOLELY by date?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting

I find this really annoying and it gets worse all the time. The addition to not only sort answers based on upvotes is great - things get outdated and new answers might keep it up to date. At the start, it felt like in the top 10 answers it was 50% highly voted answers, and 50% new.

Now when I get into any question, I immediately scroll to the bottom to find the relevant answers. Why not sort answers based on votes, where recent votes are counted as more important? Keeps things up to date but does not penalize older still valid answers.

(Might also be that I am in some A/B test.)

Comment: Happened to me more than once, all good. Annoying every time, even for veteran users.

Comment: ha looks stack overflow implemented it. How the turns table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is the sort option you choose becomes "permanent" in the sense that the site remembers the chosen option wherever you go, and no matter what device you're using.

At some point, you misclicked "Oldest" option of answers, or followed a link containing the querystring `?answertab=oldest` which has the same outcome.

To fix that, and see answers sorted by votes again, just click "Votes" and you're OK:

[image: sort answers by votes]